# How to provide alternatives for vlookup in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have created a macro to automate the building of a report. I want, in a part of a code, to provide the alternative to vlookup other values, if it cannot find them. I cannot make it run correctly. It does not crush or say anything, but the last alternative I give to it, it does not perform it. In more detail, it does not vlookup the value with "C2".
The last alternative is provided below

```
cell3.Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2&""P2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)),"""",IF(VLOOKUP(A2&""P2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)=0,"""",VLOOKUP(A2&""C2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)))"
```

The entire part of the code with vlookup is provided below

```
With Range("J2:J" & LastRow)
.Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)),"""",IF(VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)=0,"""",VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)))"
.Value = .Value
End With
Dim cell3 As Range
For Each cell3 In Range("J2:J" & LastRow)
If IsEmpty(cell3.Value) = True Then
cell3.Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2&""P2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)),"""",IF(VLOOKUP(A2&""P2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)=0,"""",VLOOKUP(A2&""C2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)))"
End If
Next cell3
```

Comment: `it does not perform it.` does that mean that it never puts the formula in the cell?  If so try `cell3.value = ""` instead of `IsEmpty(cell3.Value) = True`

Comment: Do you know what `VLOOKUP(A2&""P2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)` returns, if you run that on it's own?  Is it an error, 0 or another value?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it correctly! The formulas separately, they run great. But when I try to combine them in the cell3.Formula=.... then, it only places the value for the VLOOKUP(A2&""P2"",MARM!A:G,7,0) but, when this vlookup does not exist, it does not place the value for VLOOKUP(A2&""C2"",MARM!A:G,7,0), which I want to be the alterative. It just leaves the cell empty . the vlookup value for VLOOKUP(A2&""C2"",MARM!A:G,7,0), however exists, so it is a problem with how I wrote this line of code

Comment: In the first you write all formulas at once so A2 becomes A3, A4, etc further down the column. In the second, you explicitly write A2 into each new formula so it does not change. btw, IFERROR is better than IF(ISERROR.

Comment: @Jeeped I am sorry buddy but I didnt understand that . can you please explain it a bit more

Comment: Just to clarify my problem a bit more... I want for every cell3 to have as value VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0). If this value does not exist then VLOOKUP(A2&""P2"",MARM!A:G,7,0) and if this value does not exist then VLOOKUP(A2&""C2"",MARM!A:G,7,0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula should work (based on your last comment):

```
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2&""B2"",MARM!A:G,7,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2&""P2"",MARM!A:G,7,0),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2&""C2"",MARM!A:G,7,0),""Not Found"")))
```

The problem I see is the one @Jeeped mentioned, that it will place the lookup against cell `A2` for every row. That can be adjusted though, by changing each reference to `A2` to

```
... (A" & cell3.Row & ""B2""...
```

or you can capture cell3.Row as a variable

```
Dim myRow as Long
myRow = cell3.Row

    ... (A" & myRow & ""B2""...
```

Comment: unfortunately, even though the code from what I see is exactly what I want, it says there is a syntax error

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas - Fixed. (There needed to be double quotes around "Not Found"

Answer (score 1):

First thing I'm noticing is the cell3.Formula initial if-condition not having a condition:

```
"=If(
    ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2&""P2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)), _ 'PROBLEM; you have values, are they <> something?
    """", _ 'True-function
    IF( _ 'False-function
        VLOOKUP(A2&""P2"",MARM!A:G,7,0)=0, _ 'Has legit condition
        """", _ 'True-function
        VLOOKUP(A2&""C2"",MARM!A:G,7,0) _ 'False-function
    ) _
)"
```

I would recommend saving a step and just not insert the formula using VBA but to have VBA do the math, similar to :

```
cell3.Formula= Application.IfError( Application.VLookup( ... etc.
```